# Is there a "tag" correspondent?

Tags: ios, swift, tags

I'm wondering if there is another thing such as the `tag`?

I'm already using tags on my images but I have to use multiple tags in order to create my code, which I haven't found a way to do... Therefore I'm wondering if there is another thing that works similar to the `tag`? Another way to "mark" an image?

(`image.tag = 1`) ---> example of a tag.

Comment: image.tag = [[Nsstring stringwithformate:@"100%i",dynamic value]integerValue];  my understanding is right or wrong?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P I'm already using a tag (`Image1.tag = 1`)  -- but I'm wondering if I can have a second tag to the same variable? For example `Image1.secondtag = 2`

Comment: Name them? Then use UIImage(named: "")

Comment: are you set programatically or set in interface. which is using in tableview or common view

Comment: @Dershowitz123 wouldnt that give you a new instance of UIImage rather than giving the old one that is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Singleton class to keep track of the relation between a `UIImage` and a tag.

```
class TaggedImages {
    static let sharedInstance = TaggedImages()
    private var dict = [Int:Set<UIImage>]()
    private init() { }

    func add(tag:Int, to image:UIImage) {
        var set = dict[tag] ?? Set<UIImage>()
        set.insert(image)
        dict[tag] = set
    }

    func remove(tag:Int, to image:UIImage) {
        var set = dict[tag] ?? Set<UIImage>()
        set.remove(image)
        dict[tag] = set
    }

    func images(with tag: Int) -> [UIImage] {
        guard let set = dict[tag] else { return [] }
        return Array(set)
    }

    func tags(by image: UIImage) -> [Int] {
        return dict.filter { $0.1.contains(image) }.map { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

As you can see this class contains a dictionary where the key is an `Int` (the tag) and the value is a `Set` of `UIImage(s)`.

Now we can

- associate to a given tag a group of images.
- and each images can be associated to a variable number of tags.

### Extending UIImage

Next let's add 4 methods to `UIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func add(tag:Int) {
        TaggedImages.sharedInstance.add(tag, to: self)
    }

    func remove(tag:Int) {
        TaggedImages.sharedInstance.remove(tag, to: self)
    }

    var tags: [Int] {
        return TaggedImages.sharedInstance.tags(by: self)
    }

    func has(tag tag:Int) -> Bool {
        return self.tags.contains(tag)
    }
}
```

All methods defined in the previous extension use the `TaggedImages` shared instance to:

1. save a relation between the current image and a tag
2. remove a relation image-tag
3. retrieve all the tags associated to the current image

### How to use it

```
let sky = UIImage()
sky.add(tag: 1)
sky.add(tag: 2)
sky.add(tag: 3)
sky.tags // [2, 3, 1]

sky.has(tag: 1) // true
sky.has(tag: 2) // true
sky.has(tag: 100) // false

sky.remove(tag:1)
sky.has(tag: 1)  // false

sky.remove(tag:1)
sky.has(tag: 1) // false
sky.tags // [2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a key to each image value and store them in a dictionary.

```
// First make an array of images
var ArrayOfImages = [UIImage]
// code to populate array
// Use ArrayOfImages.append(image), and add tag to each image.
// Then, Make a dictionary like so.
var dict : [Int : UIImage] = [:]
for index in 0...(ArrayOfImages.count - 1)  {
    dict[intvalueofChoice] = ArrayOfImages[index]  
}
```

Basically each image corresponds to a tag, and also is a value that corresponds to a key of type integer.

To access the image of specific tag that you chose,

```
var image =  dict[specificTag] // gives you your result..
//  or 
var image = yoursuperView.viewWithTag(specificTag)
```

Did I get your question right?

I think with this method, you can use multiple dictionaries to store the same images with different integer key values, or different "tags"